# Visualize sinus-generator in Python3.5, pyaudio, numpy, matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, python-3.5

I am trying to visualize a sinus generator, but get the error

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

I thought the dimensions were the same, but obviously they are not.
The sinus generator is a standard

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.08     # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 192000       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 3.0   # in seconds, may be float
f = 257.0        # sine frequency, Hz, may be float
f2 = 258.0
f3 = 300.0
f4 = 301.0

oma = 2000.0

a = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)
b = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f2/fs)).astype(np.float32)
c = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f3/fs)).astype(np.float32)
d = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f4/fs)).astype(np.float32)

om = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*oma/fs)).astype(np.float32)

# generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
samples = om*(a+b+c+d)


# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=2,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)

# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively) 
stream.write(volume*samples)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

To which I added matplotlib but could not get to work. I am trying to visualize in the interval 0 - 2*np.pi, both the individual waves and the aggregate function.

Online there is a solution, but it is limited to two frequencies.
[Wave interference beat frequency](https://academo.org/demos/wave-interference-beat-frequency/)

The latest iteration of plt is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
x = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi]

plt.rc('lines', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(samples,x)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message implied that the dimensions of the `x` and `y` arrays passed to `plt.plot` are not compatible. You can check this with

```
samples.shape
# (576000,)

x.shape
# (7,)
```

There are 576000 data points in `samples` but only 7 in `x`. You most likely want the time on the x-axis, so you will need to define `x`as

```
x = np.arange(fs*duration) / fs
```

Then you can plot your data with

```
plt.plot(x, samples)
```

[image]

1. (Note that x comes first.)
2. (You can also omit x `plt.plot(samples)`, which will give you just the sample numbers on the x-axis).